# Python TypeError: can't concat bytes to str

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to sending a data with socket and I am having problem named **"builtins.TypeError: can't concat bytes to str"**.

It's the packet I am trying to send:

```
pack('!i', int(0))+pack('!b', int(this.lastPacketID))+pack('!h', int(2))+"br"+pack('!h', int(2))+"br"+pack('!i', int(this.authKey))+pack('!i', int(this.authKeyLogin))
```

Answer (score 1):

"br" is a string, and pack returns a bytes object.
replace "br" with b"br" and it should work

Answer (score 0):

`pack()` returns a bytes object and `"br"` is a string object, usually you need to encode a string to turn it into bytes but in your case you can solve this by just making python treat `"br"` as bytes: `b"br"`